# Every time to boot my system, the brightness get reset to 100%

Tags: grub2, system-installation, brightness

Earlier , I couldn't even change the screen brightness by any means(Fn keys and Brightness settings).Then I came across a solution , which required me to edit the following lines

```
File:/etc/grub.d/10_linux
changes:
edit $4 to args=”acpi_backlight=vendor $4″
```

This enabled me to change the screen brightness , But it is reset to 100% on every reboot.
I have tried installing xbacklight , it just doesn't work.